# An audio tag in HTML blocks the other tags

Tags: html

I added this code to my HTML page, the problem with it is that when I place the audio tag before the other tags (like div ect...) So they are not displayed on the page but only the audio is displayed, and when I put the audio tag under the other tags then the audio is not displayed and not heard. What could be the problem?

```
<span>       
   <div class="d3">
      <button id="b1">some text</button>
      <button id="b1">some text</button>
   </div>
<audio controls autoplay loop src="data:audio/ogg;base64,MYBASE64STRING"/>
</span>
```

Comment: Add `</audio>`  and the other html will be shown

Comment: Right .... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `audio` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-audio-element) is **not** a *void* element.

> **Tag omission in text/html:**
> Neither tag is omissible.

The end tag is mandatory.

The rest of the content can't be seen because you have placed it **inside** the audio element.

Comment: What still does not work is the automatic playback
It starst just after pressing

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: @Tomer  — Audio elements aren't allowed to autoplay. Webpages that just start playing noise are annoying so browsers require interaction first.